# Why catch block did not rethrow the error further?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I am trying to extract data from the database and problem occurred when there is no data available and then extrectedData variable return null value so that will throw error and this error did not rethrow further so what is problem here?

here is the code :-

```
try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url1));
      final extrectedData = json.decode(response.body);
      // print(extrectedData);
      final List<Product> lodedProducts = [];

      var url =
          "https://my-shop-1af19-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/isFavorite/$userId.json?auth=$authToken";

      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);

      (extrectedData as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        lodedProducts.add(
          Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: prodData['title'],
            description: prodData['description'],
            price: prodData['price'],
            imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
            isFavorite:
                favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false,
          ),
        );
        _items = lodedProducts;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('error Occured');
      // print(error.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
```

here is the output when the extrectedData variables value is null :

```
I/flutter ( 7560): error Occured
E/flutter ( 7560): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter ( 7560): #0      Products.fetchAndSetProducts
products.dart:85
E/flutter ( 7560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7560):
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in: `(extrectedData as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((prodId, prodData) {`

the `extrectedData` is null, and you're trying to cast it to a `Map<String, dynamic>`, which results in the error.

Even though you have a `try-catch` block around the code, the error occurs inside the `forEach` loop, which is not directly inside the try block. you should move the try block inside the `forEach` loop.

```
(extrectedData as Map<String, dynamic>?).forEach((prodId, prodData) {
  try {
    // your trying 
  } catch (error) {
    // your catching 
    print('Error Occured Inside Loop: $error')
  }
});
```